# Difference between 漢字辞典 and 漢和辞典

Tags: words, dictionary

Could you please explain to me which is the difference between 漢字辞典 and 漢和辞典?

For what I have understood, both dictionaries explain for a certain kanji its meaning and origin, and also tell its readings, the number and order of strokes, the words and 熟語 in which that kanji appears and so on, so I don't see the difference between both dictionaries.

Besides, I suppose that 漢字辞典 is used for looking information about kanji, but then, has 漢和辞典 an extra use? Is there something for what you should use a 漢和辞典 instead of a 漢字辞典?

Comment: 「漢語辞典」もありますよね。https://www.iwanami.co.jp/book/b256660.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia only has the entry for 漢和辞典. It says 漢字辞典 is an alternative name of 漢和辞典 for children:

> ##### [漢和辞典](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BC%A2%E5%92%8C%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8)
>
> **小学生向けのものは**基本的に常用漢字や人名用漢字を網羅した2000字から3000字程度で、学習しやすいように漢字の成り立ちや豆知識を豊富な図版で解説したものが多い。漢字の学習が主であるため、**漢和辞典ではなく漢字辞典と題する傾向にある**。

This page has an explanation from a dictionary author:

> ##### [漢和辞典は漢字辞典とどうちがう？](https://kadobun.jp/serialstory/shinjigen/75.html)
>
> 今は、ちょっとレベル高めのものが「漢和辞典」、やさしいものが「漢字辞典」と呼ばれることが多いかもしれません。

So larger ones that contain rare words and words used only in [kanbun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanbun) are usually called 漢和辞典. High schoolers and serious researchers use them. As the second link above says, the original meaning of 漢和 is "Kanbun-to-Japanese", just as 英和 means "English-to-Japanese". It tends to sound more authentic and professional. On the other hand, the name 漢字辞典 is used alternatively for smaller ones for kanji beginners.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It has helped me a lot to understand the difference between both names. :)